# RegEx Problem: Valid URL does not match, but should

Tags: c#, regex

I posted a similar question earlier, but I now realize I should have been more thorough.

I've tested a number of the URL/URI expressions listed on regexlib.com, but I can't get any of them to work as desired:

```
msn.com
msn-msn.net
yahoo.c!om
http://www.yahoo.com
msn msn
test ! number 1
```

Here is how I desire them to act:

```
msn.com (match)
msn-msn.net (match)
yahoo.c!om (fail)
http://www.yahoo.com (match)
msn msn (fail)
test ! number 1 (fail)
```

I'm using the tester here: http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx before testing in my own app (C#, .NET 4.0)

The expression that is closest is this, but it doesn't match the http://www.yahoo.com one:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*
```

Any help is appreciated. Additionally, somebody should come up with a more human-readable equivalent to RegEx...this stuff is a nightmare.

Thanks,
Beems

Comment: What about `https://fribjatz.pr/index.php?p=omghash&filthypizza#toystory2` and `ftp://milkdud.localdomain/pub/funkytoaster/`?

Comment: @kojiro. Both of those pass using the following ("[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?"), which is good. I'm doing additional parsing and testing beyond the regex to handle different scenarios. (so if FTP, then do X, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't guarantee that the URL-esque pattern you're trying to match has a scheme/protocol, then the safest thing to do is match against [top-level domains](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/):

```
^(https?://)[^/]*.([possibly|really|long|list|of|valid|top|level|domains][2])
```

From your post it's evidently not necessary to go into the path, hash, or querystring parts of a URL, so that's it!

Comment: You're right, I'm not concerned about the path, really. Also, I don't need to validate whether the TLD is proper, so this isn't an issue either.

Comment: But you're not parsing text in which someone can type a domain? For instance: www.yahoo.com.and in the next sentence maybe forget the first space?

Answer (score 0):

This one appears to work as desired:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?
```

Can anyone see any issues with this in regards to my original query? I don't need to validate whether the TLD is proper, so this isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with kojiro

But this does match your tests

http://www.rubular.com/r/gUb4U6Pzux

Comment: According to that Ruby RegEx tester link, none of those pass. I'm not sure what that means, in the end.